# Apache.Zeppelin Docker+SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, docker, apache-zeppelin

I try to work with SQL Server data using Apache.Zeppelin Docker image.

1. Run this docker
   docker run --name zeppelin -p 8088:8080 -v /zeppelin-sqlserver/notebook -v /zeppelin-sqlserver/conf -d yorek/zeppelin-sqlserver:latest
2. Run Zeppelin GUI http://localhost:8088
3. Edited the interpreter SQL Server: entered my SQL Server instance name, database, user name, password
4. Created the note in Notebook.
5. All is ok, but when I try to run query, for example:
   Select @@version
   to test how it works I receive:

   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/security/UserGroupInformation$AuthenticationMethod

What is incorrect? What need to fix?
May be I need the other Zeppelin docker?

Comment: `http://localhost:8080` versus `-p 8088:8080`... could you be connecting to the wrong Zeppelin container?

Comment: No, I have fixed. When I run the docker it gave me message that port is busy, i have changed it.